# I have a question I want to ask but I can't find the appropriate place to ask it

Tags: support, site-recommendation

"*What is the percentage of direct workers in an automotive production plant compared to all the employees?*"

**Details:**
I am not asking for specific numbers of any production plant. I want to know the general direct worker/employee ratio of a plant. The plants I am interested in are the ones that mass produce for international brands. Including the country the plant is in would also be helpful for categorizing the information.

Example: if there are 1000 employees working usually 700 of them are direct workers etc.

I am looking for estimates backed up with sources or personal experience. Also there may be multiple shifts in a production plant so I am looking for the ratio in a single shift since all the jobs may not get a night shift.

Direct worker means a worker directly working on the production line while employee means all the the people getting paid in that plant.

**Edit**: Added more information.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a bad question to ask, but I doubt there's any SE site with the necessary expertise. Maybe try chat of some vaguely-similar site, like Engineering, Workplace, etc.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yeah that is what I fear. My next step will be trying the chat rooms.

Comment: I think you ought to modify the title, Meta is getting a lot of off-topic question that should be posted on Maths, SO, SU, etc. and this title looks like a ruse to bypass inspection. Saying that, wouldn't something connected with statistics be the place you're looking for? https://stats.stackexchange.com/ (**Cross Validated**) try posting on their [meta page](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/) for guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Your question will need more information, regardless of the site you ask it on. The kind of car being produced will greatly affect the answer: mass-market cars are typically produced in factories with a high degree of automation (robotics), so a lower ratio of "direct workers" compared to a small boutique automotive company with higher ratio and a higher-priced product.

It will also be affected by the country the plant is located in. Highly unionised Western countries will likely have a lower ratio, since labour costs are prohibitive. In countries where labour is cheap, automation is not so critical.

It will also depend on what you define as "all employees". Are you just counting those actually engaged in production at the plant, or are you including design department, procurement, administration, sales, marketing, legal, finance, parts, franchising, global domination, etc?

Comment: I will edit with to add more information, thanks for the help.